# Are there YouTube keyboard shortcuts for moving forward and backward through a video's chapters?

Tags: youtube, keyboard-shortcuts

There are many [keyboard shortcuts](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7631406?hl=en) available while watching a Youtube video. Are there shortcuts to move forward and backward through a [video's chapters](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/9884579?hl=en) by using a keyboard?

Comment: It isn't possible as of now

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There now are:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>←</kbd> on Windows, <kbd>⌥ opt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>←</kbd> on Mac.

You can see a list of all shortcuts on YouTube by clicking on your user avatar in the top right corner and then selecting "Keyboard shortcuts".

Comment: This is the right answer:
on a mac: ⌥ + ▶ (OPTION + RIGHT-ARROW)
on windows: CTRL + RIGHT-ARROW

Comment: Thank you, @Ansjovis86 - I updated the answer to reflect the current state.

Comment: doesnt work on mac

Answer (score 5):

There is a chrome extension called [Tweaks for YouTube](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tweaks-for-youtube/ogkoifddpkoabehfemkolflcjhklmkge) that allows this:

[image: Image of tweaks for youTube]

It binds `n` to next chapter and `p` to previous chapter

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can :) You just press:

- on a mac: `⌥ + ▶` (OPTION + RIGHT-ARROW)
- on windows: CTRL + RIGHT-ARROW

Comment: I'm probably in a different parallel universe, because those mac keys don't work for me. They just move forward 5 seconds. Yes, the video has chapters.

Comment: I get the 5 sec forward when I press  RIGHT-ARROW without the option key

Comment: I must have somehow made it back to the normal universe, because now it works as you described! Either that, or there was a speck of dust below the option key.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be a native keyboard shortcut for chapter navigation as of the writing of this answer. Details:

- The [Keyboard shortcuts for YouTube](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7631406?hl=en) help center article does not list chapter navigation in the list of shortcuts
- Hitting `Shift` + `?` while on youtube.com brings up the list of shortcuts, and chapters are not in that list either.

[image: screenshot captured on August 8, 2021]